# How to shift row values left in a dataframe to replace NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a huge dataframe with 40 columns (10 groups of 4 columns), with value in some groups and NaN for others. I want the values for all the row left-shifted, such that wherever values be present in that row, the final Dataframe should be filled with Group1 -> Group 2 -> Group 3 and so on.

Here is a sample dataframe and the required output below:

[image: Dataframe df1]

Here is the required output:

[image: Dataframe df2]

I have used the below code to achieve shifting the values left. However, if a value is missing in an available group, e.g. Item 2 type-1, or Item 3 cat-2, the below code will ignore that and will replace it with the value to its right, and so on.

```
v = df1.values
a = [[n]*v.shape[1] for n in range(v.shape[0])]
b = pd.isnull(v).argsort(axis=1, kind = 'mergesort')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(v[a,b],df1.index,df1.columns)
```

How to achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Please include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not link or embed external images of source code or data. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Comment: Please include a _small_ subset of your data as a __copyable__ piece of code that can be used for testing as well as your expected output for the __provided__ data. See  [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888).